# Sitecore 8 easy way to get Item in internal link?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7, sitecore8.2

I have several General Link Fields, that are used as internal Links, so a Sitecore Item.

I need that "target" Items in my code, and I have the feeling that I am doing it in a horrible complex way:

```cs
LinkField lf = myItem.Fields["My Link"];
if (lf != null)
{
    if (lf.Value != null)
    {
        ID targetID;
        if (ID.TryParse(lf.Value, out targetID))
        {
            Item targetItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(targetID);
            {
                if (targetItem != null)
                {
                    // go on with code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone know a more easy way to get this target Item?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TargetItem` property of the `LinkField` without custom code:

```cs
Item targetItem;

LinkField linkField = myItem.Fields["My Link"];
if (linkField != null && linkField.IsInternal)
{
    targetItem = linkField.TargetItem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marek, this is easy :)

Comment: @Bgl86 glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi Marek. I have just tested it, it is now working. TargetItem is Null. Only the Value Property has the Item Guid. I am using a DropTree as field

Comment: Ok Got it. I need to use a ReferenceField and not a LinkField on a DropTree